# How to get the FormatDropDownListFor selected value in Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a FormatDropDownListFor in my view like this

```
<%: Html.FormatDropDownListFor(m => m.ProductHoldTypeKey, Model.ProductHoldTypeOptions.ConvertWithSelection(Model.ProductHoldTypeKey))%>
```

in Model:

```
[DisplayName("Product Hold Type")]
[HtmlProperties(CssClass = "field-short")]
public long? ProductHoldTypeKey { get; set; }
public IList<SelectListItem> ProductHoldTypeOptions { get; set; }
```

in Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetJob()
{
  jobViewModel.ProductHoldTypeOptions = _jobService.GetProductHoldType();

  if (jobViewModel.ProductHoldTypeKey == 2)// I am getting null here
  {
            // will do some task;
  }
 }
```

I am getting null in ProductHoldKey, I want the selected value which is showing in View.
Please someone help me.

What I am trying to do is, based on selected option of one dropdown i am trying to remove and add the one item in other dropdown, if is it possible by jQuery then someone please let me know some example code.

Comment: The controller action you posted is GET method that is taking value from `_jobService`. Please show us the POST method code.

Comment: in Post method I am getting the value, I want the selected value in Get

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your get code gets value from DB/data-store. You will get what you have stored. Have you stored selected item in DB?

Comment: Yes I am getting values from DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#ProductHoldTypeKey").val() == "2") {
        $('#WorkStatusKey option[value="1"]').remove();
 });   

 $("#ProductHoldTypeKey").change(function () {
    if ($("#ProductHoldTypeKey").val() == "2") {
       $('#WorkStatusKey option[value="1"]').remove(); }
    else if ($("#ProductHoldTypeKey").val() == "3") {
       $("<option value="1">OPEN</option>").appendTo("#WorkStatusKey"); }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question and the comments make the first part of your question a bit confusing.

As with the second part, i.e. based on selected option of one dropdown, remove and add the one item in other dropdown please see the below code.

You can either code in document ready or hook change event

HTML

```
<select id="abc">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>
<select id="xyz">
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
    <option>Six</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
if ($('#abc').find('option:selected').text() == "One") {
    $('#abc').find('option:selected').remove();
    $("<option>").text("Seven").appendTo("#xyz");
}
```

In this example, if the selected item is `One` in first dropdown, it is removed and another item `Seven` is added to 2nd dropdown
See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jhBa/1/)